# How to close an open form in Visual Basic using a button?

Tags: vb.net, button

I am working on a game, and it has a simple menu system. One of the buttons, simply known as 'Button1', should close the menu form and load up the game window. While it opens the game window, it does not close the menu window. Is there a way to make it so that it closes one form and opens another.

Game window name = GameBoard

Menu window name = Form2

Code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Form2 As New GameBoard
    Form2.ShowDialog()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to be able to close the startup form without closing the application then you need to change the project settings to close when the last form closes, rather than the default of when the startup form closes. You then need to open the new form before closing the startup form, and you obviously have to call `Show` rather than `ShowDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the form is not closed is because `Form2` is opened with [`ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog):

```
Form2.ShowDialog()
' This will not execute until Form2 is closed
Me.Close()
```

This will pause execution of the code in `Button1_Click` *until after* `Form2` is closed, as per the docs for `ShowDialog()`:

> Shows the form as a modal dialog box.

You could, alternatively, just do `Form2.Show()`, which would not open it as a dialog and allow the remainder of your code to run:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Form2 As New GameBoard
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Alternatively, close the current form before opening `Form2`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Form2 As New GameBoard
    Me.Close()
    Form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the current form is the startup form and the application is set to close when the startup firm closes, which is the default. In that case, none of those options will work. The app needs to be set to close when the last firm closes and then Show must be called before Close.

Comment: Form2 is the startup form, but it is the one that needs to be closed when the button is pressed, and GameBoard is the one that the button is supposed to open, I tried both of these pieces of code, and they do work, but the game window does not open.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I hadn't considered that it was the startup form.  I'll revise the answer to reflect that a bit later